# Use of header function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding a contact to my database with a form on the page add.php, the INSERT code for this form is on another page we'll call php.php page. In php.php I have a header function which I would like to have redirect the user to another page edit.php?ID=100, ID=100 being the contact that was just entered. How would I do this, do I need to do a fetch from the db before the header function and INSERT query?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['$fname'])) {

  header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/contacts/edit/?ID=<? echo $row['ID]; ?>");

  $connect = mysql_connect (...)

  mysql_select_db ("mydb);

  $ID = $_POST['ID'];
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];

  $sql = ("INSERT INTO contacts (fname, lname) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]')");

  mysql_query($sql,$con) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: You're already in a block of PHP code, you don't need `<?` and `?>` again. `...edit/?ID=" . $row['ID]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) is the function you're looking for. It'll return the AUTO_INCREMENT ID of the field that was just inserted. You can then plug that into your header redirect. Just make sure to do the header redirect AFTER you insert the contact. It'll work just fine.

Code that should work:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['$fname'])) {

$connect = mysql_connect (...)

mysql_select_db ("mydb");

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (fname, lname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')";

mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/contacts/edit/?ID=".mysql_insert_id($connection));

exit;
}

?>
```

The code you posted was also susceptible to MySQL injections, so I mysql_real_escape_string'd your input to prevent that from happening. Always sanitize input before putting it into your query. I encourage you to look at the MySQLi functions that PHP has to offer.

Comment: Thanks, this returns ID=0 everytime

Comment: then that means the query is not being inserted, are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't put in `$connection` in `.mysql_insert_id()` but it still works. Is there a benefit to putting that in?

Comment: I just noticed you had a $connection in your mysql_query, so I figured I'd do the same by letting mysql_insert_id know which connection to use. You don't have to fill that in for any mysql functions, as the mysql functions will automatically fill that in with whatever open mysql connection the script has, I was just following your pattern. :)

Comment: I see, and in using mysqli there needs to be at least 1 parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the headers **after** the current script has done all that you want it to do. Sending headers doesn't necessarily immediately cancel the execution of that script; it can still persist for a bit, but you should do after you do your SQL calls.

Answer (score 0):

The header doesn't terminate the run of the script.
If you use location redirect is a good practice to exit from the script, what you did correct.

Be aware one thing, do not put any output to the stdout before the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed php code in the `header` function (the `<? echo $row['ID]; ?>`). To achieve what you are trying to do, you should have the `INSERT` code before the header function. Then you should retrieve the ID of the contact you just entered and then call the header function, like so (assuming `$id` is the retrieved ID):

```
header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/contacts/edit/?ID=".$id);
```

To retrieve the ID of the last inserted row, you can use the `mysql_insert_id` function ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)), though it is recommended you use the mysqli version.