# Can INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT queries be put in the same file

Tags: php, mysql

I have folders and pages /admin/add/index.php, /admin/edit/index.php & /admin/view/index.php which all are requiring page /admin/php.php which has all of my php code for each, I'm getting fail to open stream errors. Should I be seperating them with `<? ?>` or is doing what I'm doing not possible or the best approach?

My admin/php.php file:

```
<?php
FOR ADD CONTACT PAGE

require ("../../dbandpassword.php");
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lastname']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')"; 

mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/admin/edit/?ID=".mysqli_insert_id($con));

exit;
}
FOR EDIT CONTACT PAGE

require ("../../dbandpassword.php");
$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lastname']);

$sql = "UPDATE table SET `firstname` = '$firstname', `lasttname` = '$lastname' WHERE `table`.`ID`  = '$ID' LIMIT 1";

mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

FOR VIEW CONTACT PAGE

require ("../../dbandpassword.php");

$ID = $_GET['ID'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='$ID' limit 1" or die ('Error: ' .mysqli_error());

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error: ' .mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$space = (!empty($row['firstname']) && !empty($row['lastname'])) ? ' ' : '';        
$name = $row['firstname'].$space.$row['lastname'];       

mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

FOR VIEW ALL CONTACTS PAGE

require ("../dbandpassword.php");

$ID=$_GET['ID'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstname IN ('Bob','Joe') AND lastname = 'Smith' ORDER BY date DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$space = (!empty($row['firstname']) && !empty($row['lastname'])) ? ' ' : '';        
$name = $row['firstname'].$space.$row['lastname'];   

mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

Comment: `I'm getting fail to open stream errors.` -- It's not because you're putting INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT queries in the same file.

Comment: You're missing a quote somewhere.

Comment: You grabbed the unupdated code from earlier! I forgot to remove that sprintf(, I updated it in [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217378/use-of-header-funtion/11217575#11217575).

Comment: @Sean - I'll check that and update, thanks.

Comment: Yes Robert, you are correct. The problem is that its not opening the file to where my db and password is. So /admin/index.php says that ../../dbandpassword.php fails to open but /admin/edit/index.php works fine. If I change the path to ../dbandpassword.php then /admin/index.php doesn't work and /admin/edit/index.php does work. The error keeps referencing the same require file line no matter which way I do it...

Comment: You should be checking to see if your dynamic variables are set, or you'll get a ton of undefined errors if one of the form fields doesn't get filled in. `$ID = isset($_POST['id']) ? (int) $_POST['id'] : 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its better to create a php file and then create separate function for each of the action like

```
function insert()
{

}

function delete()
{

}

function update()
{

}

function fetch()
{

}
```